# How do I in-place modify each element of a 1D Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen

I have a 1D eigen array (`Eigen::Array<double,Dynamic,Dynamic>`) of doubles, and I want to modify each element in the array *in place*. However, I'm not really sure how to do this. I'm considering this:

```
Eigen::Array<double,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic> arr1D;
// ...

// Threshold function:
arr1D.unaryExpr([](double& elem)
{
    elem = elem < 0.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0;
}
);
```

But this seems like a bit of a hack because the [Eigen Reference](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ArrayBase.html#a23fc4bf97168dee2516f85edcfd4cfe7) examples only give examples of `.unaryExpr` where it is used with a functor that returns a value (and then the whole method just returns a different array). In my case, I was hoping to avoid the need for creating a new array.

I'm new to Eigen so I thought I might be missing something here, input is appreciated.

**EDIT: I understand that I can replace the above simply with `arr1D = arr1D >= 0.0`, but please note that this is just an example**

Comment: `unaryExpr` is a `const` function so it will not give you the possibility to modify values in place (i.e. give you a non-const reference). Did you try your piece of code? I guess it won't compile.

Comment: @leemes well it compiles but doesn't seem to modify the array, kinda weird.

Comment: In this case the implementation seems to use a local copy of the scalar value to pass it to your functor. What's strange that it accepts a function returning void...

Comment: @leemes maybe this is just one of those times where I need to adapt my thinking to the Eigen 'paradigm'? Maybe in-place modification just isn't *something that you do* in Eigen?

Comment: Possibly... It's even possible that Eigen detects "self-assignment" like `arr1D = arr1D.unaryExpr(...)` (technically, self-assignment means something different but I guess you know what I mean). I heard Eigen is very very clever with enabling low-level optimizations behind the scenes. (I never used it though.)

Comment: @leemes well I'll do as you suggested and if I profile any bottlenecks later I'll come back with more questions!

Comment: You can proof this by debug-printing the whole array (captured-by-ref) within the lambda. If you see successive modifications, it proofs that Eigen chose to evaluate the operation in place. If you see the original contents N times, the opposite is the case, i.e. Eigen chose to evaluate before the assignment. I'm not sure if these optimizations count for Matrix and Array, but they are done for Matrix (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.unaryExpr` returns "view" to original data transformed by given function. It doesn't do transformation of original data.

You cannot change argument passed to transformation function. Your code is compiled only because you have not triggered template instantiation of appropriate code. If assign result to value then it fails to compile:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
    using namespace Eigen;

    ArrayXd x, y;
    y = x.unaryExpr([](double& elem)
    {
        elem = elem < 0.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0;
    }); // ERROR: cannot convert const double to double&
}
```

Exact place of error is in `Eigen` internals:

```
EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE const Scalar coeff(Index index) const
{
  return derived().functor()( derived().nestedExpression().coeff(index) );
  //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - your lambda
}
```

---

I think the easiest way to do in-place with `Eigen` is:

```
ArrayXd x = ArrayXd::Random(100);
x = x.unaryExpr([](double elem) // changed type of parameter
{
    return elem < 0.0 ? 0.0 : 1.0; // return instead of assignment
});
```

`unaryExpr` does not return full new array/matrix - but it returns special temporary object which acts like it.

Comment: This helps. I thought it is something like std::for_each and it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Evgeny's answer is by far the best if your value types are relatively simple.

However, if you want to recreate `real()` and `complex()` (accessing portions of the `Scalar`s structure), you can use `const_cast<>` to hack it all away, which is what `real/complex()` actually do (as of v3.3.3):
(note: This code was only tested in C++1y, but could be simplified.)

```
struct Value {
  double a{1.5};
  int b{2};
};

// Savage. Use aforemention hack from scalar_real_ref_op.
struct get_mutable_a_direct {
  double& operator()(const Value& v) const {
    return const_cast<Value&>(v).a;
  }
};
// ...
MatrixX<Value> X(2, 2);
auto X_am_direct = CwiseUnaryView<get_mutable_a_direct, MatrixX<Value>>(
    X, get_mutable_a_direct());
X_am_direct.setConstant(20);
```

I've also tested out a quick wrapper, to reduce the above to something like:

```
struct get_a_flex {
  double& operator()(Value& v) const {
    return v.a;
  }
  const double& operator()(const Value& v) const {
    return v.a;
  }
};
// Less? savage.
auto X_am = unaryExprFlex(X, get_a_flex());
X_am *= 10;
cout << X_ac << endl;

// Works.
const auto& Xc = X;
auto Xc_am = unaryExprFlex(Xc, get_a_flex());
// Xc_am.setConstant(20);  // Fails as desired.
cout << Xc_am << endl;
```

You can see the code snippet here: [unary_view_mutable.cc](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/a4e9c4c/eigen_scratch/unary_view_mutable.cc#L48)

NOTE: If you want to use labmda, be sure you indicate returning a reference via `auto&`:

```
auto X_bm = unaryExprFlex(X, [](Value& v) -> auto& { return v.b; });
cout << X_bm << endl;
X_bm.setConstant(10);
cout << X_bm << endl;
```